# directoryChooser.showDialog in javaFX app is freezing application after dierctory selection

Tags: file, javafx, directory, download, freeze

```
DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(vbox_container.getScene().getWindow());
                                if (selectedDirectory == null) {
                                    Logging.log(getClass(), LogType.INFO, "USER NOT SELECT OF DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY");
                                } else {
                                    new UpdateDownload(version, selectedDirectory) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onPreExecute() {
                                            Label label = new Label("Downloading...");
                                            label.getStyleClass().addAll("text-color-white");
                                            vbox_container.getChildren().add(label);
                                        }
                                    }.execute();
                                }
```

After confirm of location in  DirectoryChooser  application is freezing for about 5 sec, than everything working fine... how to avoid described 5 secs freeze?

Comment: What does `UpdateDownload#execute()` do? If it's a blocking or otherwise long-running task then offload the task to a so-called background thread. You must never block, or run long-running tasks on, the _JavaFX Application Thread_ lest the UI become unresponsive—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: It's asyncTask - so it's impossible :) dear i found problem, i just changed version of ZuluFX jdk to latest and now freeze is not exist.